# How to enqueue jQuery asynchronously in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

My theme uses the bundled jQuery of Wordpress and I want to load it asynchronously. (Yeah, PageSpeed Insights...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a hook for this [script_loader_tag](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/script_loader_tag/). You can use it as below

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'add_async_to_script', 10, 3 );
 
function add_async_to_script( $tag, $handle, $src ) {

    //You can use this to make all async

    $tag = str_replace( ' src', ' async src', $tag );

    // You can use this to make it work as below for a specific script

    if ( 'dropbox.js' === $handle ) {
        $tag = '<script async type="text/javascript" src="' . esc_url( $src ) . '"></script>';
    }
 
    return $tag;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! Unfortunately the PageSpeed thing doesn't gives me more score if I load my scripts asynchronously. :/ I try to defer it.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the functionalities of your website, deferring or loading jquery asyncronously might possibly impact on the way the page is loaded or even break functionality. It may as well run smoothly.

But in order to give you a correct answer I must recommend you **not to do it.**

Here is some reference if you want to still try

https://wpshout.com/make-site-faster-async-deferred-javascript-introducing-script_loader_tag/